# Old body world values to new one

Tags: libgdx, box2d, gravity

I'm trying to learn box2d with libgdx. I've a character that falls down. If character collides with bonus i remove character and create smaller character to resize it. But when i create new smaller one, gravity resets itself and new motion begins for the new one like new game begining. is there anyway to transfer old characters values that occures because of gravity to new one for a non-stop motion?

Comment: I can't understand a thing bro..

Comment: @Paul He wants to create new objects that already have the same velocity and direction as the one that is being removed.

Comment: thanks Paul, more clear than my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are creating the new body in the same position and angle as the original one was? How about doing the same for velocities?

Before you remove the original body, get the linear and angular velocity of it.
(GetLinearVelocity, GetAngularVelocity)

Set those velocities in the new body when you create it.
(SetLinearVelocity, SetAngularVelocity)